# How to create docker volume in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file to start my services. I need to have a volume for my services on the host machine. From what I understood, I have to create the volume first on my host machine (using docker volume create ) and them put the volume name in my docker-compose file. I want to know whether this is the only option to create a volume? Or I can somehow create the volume on the host machine automatically in my docker-compose file?

Comment: There is [`docker-compose.yml` syntax](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference) for doing it directly in Compose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create named volume directly in docker-compose e.g.

```
version: '2.4'

services:
  ubuntu:
    image: ubuntu:18.04
    volumes:
      - myvolume:/opt/myvolume

volumes:
  myvolume: {}
```

Edit:

Volume doesn't need to exist on host machine, see example log:

```
➜ /tmp docker-compose up                                                            
Creating volume "tmp_myvolume" with default driver                                  
Creating tmp_ubuntu_1 ... done
```

Edit 2:

Answering to comment: [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference) is section where you can define configuration for some volumes. In my example I passed empty configuration but it can looks like e.g.

```
volumes:
   myvolume:
     name: othermyvolumename
     driver: nfs-driver
```

After defining volumes you can refer them in `services` section.

Comment: but myvolume should already exist on the host machine, right?

Comment: What does the second volumes do the docker-compose file? where you list all the volume? you have put {} but I've seen places with true as well, what does it mean?

Comment: I edited my answer for you - I would really appreciate if you could accept it if you think that's helpful :)

Comment: true or false in front of the volume means whether it already exist on the host machine or not?